Patching version of transient dependencies Rust
I am trying to fix a dependency issue in Rust/Cargo. I have a dependency ctclib-pp which in turn depends on ctclib-kenlm-sys which finally depends on bindgen ^0.59.2. However, for compatibility reasons I need to use version 0.60.1 or higher of bindgen (because of this).
I tried the following changes in my Cargo.toml but that does not seem to work, as this seems to install both versions next to each other.
[dependencies]
ctclib-pp = "0.2.0"

[patch.crates-io]
bindgen = { git = "https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen", tag = "v0.60.1" }

When I run cargo update I get the following notice:
warning: Patch `bindgen v0.60.1 (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen?tag=v0.60.1#9ca5f856)` was not used in the crate graph.
Check that the patched package version and available features are compatible
with the dependency requirements. If the patch has a different version from
what is locked in the Cargo.lock file, run `cargo update` to use the new
version. This may also occur with an optional dependency that is not enabled.

and the lock file now contains an unused patch
[[patch.unused]]
name = "bindgen"
version = "0.60.1"
source = "git+https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen?tag=v0.60.1#9ca5f856a35deddde0575002d76d1db4430e6c42"

Any suggestions on how to override the sub-dependency?

Just a note 0.59 and 0.60 are semver incompatible the way cargo defines it.

You can fork the bindgen repository with the 0.60.1 version, edit the package version in its Cargo.toml down to 0.59.2, and use that within your [patch] section.

So basically spoofing its version number? That seems dangerous. I hope that there are other options.

@BramVanroy "That seems dangerous" - What danger are you envisioning that wasn't already evident from coercing a crate to use a dependency version it wasn't designed for?

That's a fair point, thanks.

You will need to patch the dependent of bindgen, i.e. ctclib-pp. Copy it, and (assuming everything will compile with just this modification) modify the version of bindgen it depends on. Then, specify it in your [patch.crates-io].

Sorry, I'm new to Cargo. Can you specify in code what you mean? To clarify again: I require ctclib-pp, which depends on ctclib-kenlm-sys, which finally depends on bindgen ^0.59.2. I want to override the latter to 0.60.1.

@BramVanroy Then patch ctclib-kenlm-sys (but arguably, @kmdreko's solution is better).
